# How can keep 'this' with new function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I keep 'this' going within new function without using event.target.id

```
$(document).on('keyup','input[type=text],input[type=password]',function()
{       
    alert($(this).val());

    clearTimeout(TIMER); TIMER = setTimeout(function()
    { 
        alert($(this).val());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like you just want to bind the keyup event to the inputs, if so, I would remove the on function from the document and put it on the elements that you mean to bind to.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval#The_.22this.22_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, you just need to assign a local variable that will retain its value.

```
var $input = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('keyup','input[type=text],input[type=password]',function()
{
    var myElement=$(this)       
    alert(myElement.val());

    clearTimeout(TIMER); TIMER = setTimeout(function()
    { 
        alert(myElement.val());
    }
}
```